# Является хорошей практиков делать subscribe во вьюхе?

Tags: angular2

Вот у меня есть такой самописный интерфейс пагинатора:

```
export interface Paginator<T> {
     canMoveNext: boolean;
     canMovePrev: boolean;
     currentPageItems: T[];
     currentPageNumber: number;
     pageCount: number;
     goToFirstPage(): Observable<T[]>;
     goToLastPage(): Observable<T[]>;
     goToNextPage(): Observable<T[]>;
     goToPage(pageNumber: number): Observable<T[]>;
     goToPrevPage(): Observable<T[]>;
}
```

Как видно, он хранит текущую страницу и в тоже время при передергивании методов мы можем получить тоже самое.

=> в моей реализации у меня есть 2 пути отобразить содержимое во вьюхе:

Это привязать currentPageItems ко вьюхе, а на кнопки навигации напрямую привязать методы перемещения с вызовом `subscribe()`, либо сделать дублирующуюся прослойку в самом компонент и там выполнять подписку.

Как более чисто сделать?

Пример разметки:

```
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center fixed-bottom pb-3">
  <nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:!paginator?.canMovePrev}"><a class="page-link"
          (click)="paginator.goToPrevPage().subscribe()">Previous</a></li>
      <li *ngFor="let page of pageArray" [ngClass]="{active:paginator.currentPageNumber==page}" class="page-item"><a
          class="page-link" (click)="paginator.goToPage(page).subscribe()">{{page}}</a></li>
      <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:!paginator?.canMoveNext}"><a class="page-link"
          (click)="paginator.goToNextPage().subscribe()">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: подписки во вьюхе можно сделать только через `async` пайп

Comment: @overthesanity у меня и без пайпы работает.O_o. Пример добавил.

Comment: так нельзя делать

Comment: @overthesanity тогда получается, что лучше убрать currentPageItems из интерфейса, что бы не было соблазна, затем сделать в компоненте одноименные методы и там делать сабскрайбы?

Comment: я в общем не вижу надобности делать подписку где угодно в реализации пагинатора

Comment: пагинатор должен быть синхронный без каких либо махинаций с rxjs и прочем

Comment: @overthesanity а я за каждой страницей к серверу обращаюсь. Разве можно засинхронить в таком случае?

Comment: к серверу ведь должен не пагинатор обращаться, а компонент, компонент следит за изменением страниц и делает соответствующие запросы

Comment: @overthesanity ну так-то компонент в который встроен пагинатор и следит за страницей, далее при активности на форме пинает пагинатор с просьбой достать еще одну страницу из сети.

Comment: Оформлен кстати он в виде сервиса.

Comment: представь что ты делаешь плагин-пагинатор для нескольких команд в компании. Как разработчики этих команд должны использовать этот плагин - просто заимпортить модуль, проджектнуть app-paginator в шаблон, передать входные параметры и слушать события изменения страницы <app-paginator maxItemsPerPage="10" [items]="items" (nextPage)="nextPage()" (prevPage)="prevPage()" ? либо же проделывать какие-то махинации с хттп запросами и сервисами внутри самого пагинатора, при этом сервисы у всех команд совершенно разные

Comment: @overthesanity ну если с такой стороны думать, то да.. он не универсален и каждому нужно запилить реализацию под свои нужды.